# graph api assign manager

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to assign the manager to a user in AAD the documentation says

```
PUT /users/{id}/manager/$ref
```

but i'm not sure what to feed the $ref variable. I've tried UPN and the ID, but I keep getting

```
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
```

Here is how i'm trying to put the manager info, but clearly i'm not doing it right or I can't read the documentation from here

```
$Header = @{
    Authorization = "$($Request.token_type) $($Request.access_token)"
}

$bodyProcess = @{
    id= "string aa9999a1-1111-11a2-abab-asfdas32"
}


$body = $bodyProcess | ConvertTo-Json

$Uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/4d5f6c5a-0e69-40b6-a86d-e825582add50/manager/$ref"
$UserData = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Headers $Header -Method PUT -ContentType "application/json" -Body $Body
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks,

Comment: Are you sure you want `string` in the id??? (`id= "string aa9999a1-1111-11a2-abab-asfdas32"`)

Comment: @theo based on this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/directoryobject?view=graph-rest-1.0#json-representation and when I run the script...the "string" disappears and the url comes out right. but if it doesn't change the error whenI take it out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full script that works for me.

```
$Header = @{
    Authorization = "$($Request.token_type) $($Request.access_token)"
}

$bodyProcess = @{
   
    "@odata.id"= "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/aa9999a1-1111-11a2-abab-asfdas32"
   
}
$body = $bodyProcess | ConvertTo-Json
$Uri = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/4d5f6c5a-0e69-40b6-a86d-e825582add50/manager/$ref'
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Headers $Header -Method PUT -ContentType "application/json" -Body $Body
```